# How does Laravel's Hash Facade return different hashes for the same input string?

Tags: php, laravel

This isn't affecting my code, I am just curious. It is my understanding that Hash functions are deterministic, but Laravel's implementation returns a different Hash every time for the same string and then evaluates them all correctly on the check(). I see that there is some meta-data at the front that is sectioned by '$'s but it is the same for every hash of the string. Does Hash use some of the first characters in the last section as salt?

Comment: A new salt is probably generated each time. Assuming it's using bcrypt https://www.engineyard.com/blog/password-security-part-3 might be of interest.

Comment: Yup, what you are thinking. "The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default."

Comment: Thanks @Jonnix that link is very helpful.